# Easiest way to remove all namespaces from an XmlDocument object

Tags: xml, vb.net

I need to be able to remove the beginning and end xmlns namespaces from an XML document.

Here is sample XML document that I need to remove the namespace from:

I need to remove:

```
<ns1:OrderLoadRequest xmlns:ns1="http://Tony.com/le/GST2210/TonyShipmentsDlvryOutbound">
```

AND

```
</ns1:OrderLoadRequest>
```

FROM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns1:OrderLoadRequest xmlns:ns1="http://Tony.com/le/GST2210/TonyShipmentsDlvryOutbound"><OrderLoadRequest><UserName>GBENIN</UserName><Header><CustomIdentifier>0000370568</CustomIdentifier><Order><ShipViaCode>B1</ShipViaCode></Order><Ship><Company>COMPAGNIE WESTROCK DU CANADA INC.</Company><AddressOne>1000 CHEMIN DE L&apos;USINE</AddressOne><City>LA TUQUE</City><State>QC</State><Zip>G9X 3P8</Zip><Country>CA</Country><Phone>8196768100</Phone></Ship></Header></OrderLoadRequest></ns1:OrderLoadRequest>
```

`sFile` is loaded and contains the XML above:

```
Dim doc As New System.Xml.XmlDocument

doc.Load(sFile)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

- Load the data into a string ([`File.ReadAllText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext?view=netframework-4.8)).
- Replace `"<ns1:OrderLoadRequest xmlns:ns1=""http://Tony.com/le/GST2210/TonyShipmentsDlvryOutbound"">"`* with `""` in that string.
- Replace `"</ns1:OrderLoadRequest>"` with `""`.
- Use `doc.LoadXml(theNewString)`.

* <sub>Quotes doubled up for convenience in copying to code.</sub>

Like this...

```
Dim sFile = "C:\temp\somefile.xml"

Dim s = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(sFile)
s = s.Replace("<ns1:OrderLoadRequest xmlns:ns1=""http://Tony.com/le/GST2210/TonyShipmentsDlvryOutbound"">", "")
s = s.Replace("</ns1:OrderLoadRequest>", "")

Dim doc As New System.Xml.XmlDocument
doc.LoadXml(s)
```

Change the `http://Tony.com/le/GST2210/TonyShipmentsDlvryOutbound` part as required.

Note that `Replace` is a function, so it returns a value rather than changing it.

Comment: Hey, it's easy... that's what the question asked for. Let's see the downvoter come up with the proper way of doing it *easily* ;)

Comment: @AndyMorton - Sorry again, I am new to this and wasn't sure how to post updated code. That worked,and makes perfect sense.  Thank you again

Comment: @TonySposato You're welcome :) It can take a little practise before you suddenly go "Aha!" and a programming idea becomes clear. Although there are "correct" XML manipulation ways to solve the problem, unless someone actually posts one as an answer you might want to accept this answer like this: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) There's no rush.